# How to get notified after cloudkit synced?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, swift-data

I use Swiftdata and CloudKit. I fetch the data myself (see below). Therefore, I need to be informed when the sync of local data with the central server is completed.

```
let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>()
items = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
```

To spell it out, without this, I start the App and display local data. Then, in the background, the local data is synched. But my software doesn't know when this is done and keeps displaying outdated data - until I fetch the data anew.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way. Assuming you have a `fetchData` function that uses `descriptor`  to update data like this:

```
 func fetchData() {
     do {
        let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>()
        items = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
        // do something with the data here
     } catch {
         //...
     }
 }
```

Then the needed functionality is:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
       forName: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification,
       object: nil, 
       queue: OperationQueue.main){
           (notification) in 
                self.fetchData()
       }
```