Prepopulate container without duplication when using SwiftData and CloudKit
I'm working on my first iOS app with Swift and I'm struggling with data duplication caused by SwiftData and CloudKit.
I have created an app with iOS and watchOS targets. The iOS app can be used to modify a pre-populated database, whereas the watchOS app can display the contents of the database.
The model, let's call it Record, has items that are identified by a unique combination of two enums, storageBank: Bank and storageSlot: Slot, that each hold 6 values. The user must not be able to add or remove Records, which results in a fixed number of 36 Records.
The user may change anything stored in a Record, but not add or remove any Records.
Each user starts off with a copy of the default records and may change anything to their needs.
For testing, the app prepopulates the ModelContainer with the default data like this:
if try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Record>()).isEmpty {
    DefaultRecords.contents.forEach { container.mainContext.insert($0) }
}

This, of course, leads to duplication when enabling CloudKit. Each device pre-populates the local database before the cloud version of the database is synced in the background, leading to one set of default values per device (so, on iCloud, that's numberOfDevices * 36).
What is the best way to handle this?
Sadly there don't seem to be many tutorials or articles about SwiftData + CloudKit, probably because SwiftData is still rather new.

If I read this correctly you always have 36 objects and nothing else, if this is correct why even bother with SwiftData? Why not store all 36 objects in a file, like a json file for instance?

And do the values change per install/user or are they always the same?  Do they need to be stored in CloudKit?

But, the general answer to your question is you need to wait until the cloud sync is complete before attempting to insert any data - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760437/how-to-get-notified-after-cloudkit-synced

I have edited the question to provide a few more details.
Each user should have their own copy of the default records, which they may modify. Records can't be created or deleted, as they represent storage banks and slots of an external device.
The database must sync between devices so that the user can easily edit the records on their phone and quickly look up the records via their Apple Watch.

Then the approach is as I suggested - On launch, you need to wait until the CloudKit sync is complete before checking and creating the records if required. Another approach is to record a creation date with each record and when you detect excess records delete the newest.

@Paulw11 Hm, guess I'll have to come up with a strategy for the case that a device doesn't have a copy of the database yet and can't go online
Maybe display a splash screen while waiting for the sync to finish and add a time limit of a few seconds. If the sync doesn't finish within the time limit, I can show a button for manually initialising the database. If the sync finishes in time and the data store is still empty, the app can automatically init the database.

Yes, or use timestamps on the records and merge the records if you get multiple records

And I'll need a strategy for the case that a user wasn't signed into their Apple account and retroactively enables iCloud sync, leading to duplicates because multiple devices that previously weren't using iCloud are now syncing and creating duplicates.
I'll probably have to check the integrity of the database at every sync, and find a strategy to delete duplicates - which may be difficult as there probably isn't an easy way to find out which records belong to the same device.
Guess I'll have to think about this for a while.

Yes.  Distributed databases are hard.

Indeed they are
I was thinking about allowing multiple sets of records in a later version of the app. Maybe that's something that can be helpful in this case. Just create a new SET of records when initialising the database, and then give the user the option to delete sets.
Thank you very much for your help :-)
